# Wordpress Website Not Showing Full Width on Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

My site is set to have a centered view on desktops.

**[Screenshot of Desktop view]**

[image]

However, it is showing a centered view on mobiles as well. This is not a good experience.

**[Mobile View Screenshot]**

[image]

I want a full width view on the mobile view as well.

What would you guys suggest?

I am using the X Theme for Wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set a media query : learn more about media queries here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Requ%C3%AAtes_m%C3%A9dia/Utiliser_les_Media_queries

Something like this (on your stylesheet)

```
@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used media query for that set 100% width in your container

```
@media (max-width: 980px){
  .x-container.width {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```